# Unable to run php on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, php

I'm trying to install LAMP on Linux Mint 17.1 following this tutorial [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486).

The Apache part was okay, I can access the localhost which shows a beautiful "It works!" message.

After installing Apache2, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

which I believe worked fine.

Then I create a simple php file to show the version of the php currently installed:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/testphp.php
```

with this inside:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But when I try to access http://localhost/testphp.php it gives me a 404 error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /testphp.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I've already restarted the Apache server and tried to create another php file but got the same issue.

How can I install/run it properly on Linux Mint 17.1?

Comment: "Install LAMP on Linux Mint": I was interested to see how the article, you link to, would describe how to install Linux under Linux Mint (Apache I already have installed, and MySQL and Pretty Home Page are of no interest to me), but unfortunately it doesn't go into that at all.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04 This is a good link to install LAMP package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default directory for html seems to be `/var/www/html` and not `/var/www`.
As per the comments on the page you link to.

Comment: That is true! I'm used to older versions of Mint, I'm almost 100% sure that the default directory was just /var/www. Anyway, thank you!